# My "Meta" rep on Photo.SE differs from my main rep

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, per-site-meta

https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2361/billy-oneal -> 683
https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2361/billy-oneal -> 678

???

(Doesn't really bother me too much but figured I'd report the bug...)

Answer (score 11):

It's not a bug.

The reputation on meta sites is not updated instantly (except for this site, Meta Stack Exchange, which is not a typical per-site meta), after you get more reputation in the main site, but it is updated once per hour, according to the [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) page:

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (**synchronized hourly**), though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.

Answer (score 7):

Reputation on meta doesn't update instantly, so you're likely just running into a caching issue. It'll catch up eventually.