# How can a user have a different reputation on a per-site meta than they have on the main site?

Tags: discussion, reputation, per-site-meta

A certain user (I won't mention them here) has 4 reputation on a Stack Exchange site's per-site meta and 1 reputation on the site itself. The user is not banned or "temporarily suspended" on either the main site or the meta.

How is this possible?

Comment: Did you consider caching?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: It's definitely not caching. I cleared my cache and refreshed the browser page. 13 minutes later, it's still the same.

Comment: Try adding a per-site meta to your communities in the hamburger menu, there is always a difference in reputation there

Comment: @Luuklag It's not me, it's a different user. I'm not naming them because I don't want *meta effect* to ensue.

Comment: I just looked at you, and on main SO you have 2271 rep, on MSO you have 2272 rep. So blame server-side caching ;)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69172/158100

Comment: See also: [My “Meta” rep on Photo.SE differs from my main rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96606).

Comment: @JL2210 server caching and CDN caching exist.