# Where has my 24922 rep gone?

Tags: bug, reputation, per-site-meta, stack-exchange-button, communities-list

My rep on SU is 124927. When I go to the top bar site drop-down (the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™) it shows my Meta SU rep to be 100005 (a significant difference).

> [image]

This question, [My "Meta" rep on Photo.SE differs from my main rep - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96606/my-meta-rep-on-photo-se-differs-from-my-main-rep/96609#96609), says it can be different because of caching, and that in any case rep should be synchronised hourly:

> The reputation on meta sites is not updated instantly (except for this site, Meta Stack Exchange, which is not a typical per-site meta), after you get more reputation in the main site, but it is updated once per hour, according to the What is "meta"? How does it work? page

So we can rule out caching as I haven't had any rep changes in the last hour or so.

**So, where has my 24922 rep gone?**

Note, that if I look at my rep on Meta SU in the top bar it is correct (see the image), it is only the site drop-down that is wrong.

The same problem is affecting other site metas as well. I've had no rep changes on SO or Software Recommendations in the last 7 days and these reps don't match up either.

> [image]

Comment: I was going to say: *That is what you get when you're suspended* but realize that is unlikely to have happened here ....

Comment: @animuson Is that bug being investigated?

Comment: It is probably on the list somewhere @SonictheMaskedWerehog. But this has been the case for ages.